# Concatenating two numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays which I have to join them side-by side, for example one has a shape of (100,1,300,1) and another one has a shape of (100,1,400,1), the output shape should be (100,1,700,1). I have written below codes but I need to join both np_predict and np_predict_borders as the way I told

```
np_predict = model.predict(np.array(images))
np_predict=np_predict.reshape(np_predict.shape[0],1,np_predict.shape[1],1)

np_predict_e=model.predict(np.array(images_e))
np_predict_e = np_predict_e.reshape(np_predict_e.shape[0], 1, np_predict_e.shape[1], 1)
```

I am not sure what command I have to use in numpy to join them?

Comment: You have the [command](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) in your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), in `axis` parameter you define direction of concatenation.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros((100,1,300,1))
>>> b = np.zeros((100,1,400,1))
>>> c = np.concatenate((a,b),axis=2)
>>> c.shape
(100, 1, 700, 1)
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the direction of concatenations, and what are axis=0,1, or 2?

Comment: @Mah "The axis along which the arrays will be joined", you can understand this as dimmension, your array have 4 dim, so if you want to concat at 3rd dim, you type `axis=2`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many ways with numpy. One possibility is using `np.dstack`:

```
import numpy as np


A=np.zeros((100,1,300,1))
B = np.ones((100,1,400,1))
C = np.dstack((A,B))
print(C.shape)
```

output:

```
(100, 1, 700, 1)
```